# Generate container Drag and Drop Angular7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I need to be able to create containers to be able to drag items so that I can create groups.

For example this website: http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested

Look New Elements (Container)

```
<div class="card-top">
  <div class="card-header">
    <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> GroupUser1</span>
    <div class="card-header-actions save-button">
    <a href="#" class="card-header-action" target="_blank">
    <small class="text-muted"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Save</small>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" cdkDropList #pendingList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList2, pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="grupo-paciente" *ngFor="let item of todo" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to look into the official example for a start / inspiration: [https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

Comment: Thank you very much, if I look at the documentation but can not find anything

Comment: you got nothing? what does that mean? try: https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts

Comment: I have the fields created, the ts created and the fields created, I can drag objects between containers, but I want to create more containers dynamically